# Sudden changes to Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, namespaces, ankhsvn

I've have been using Visual Studio 2005, alongside Visual Web Developer 2008 to create asp.net web-apps in vb.  I recently installed Visual Studio 2008 alongside these, along with AnkhSVN - and have noticed a few changes which are causing issues!

The most noticable is that in my solution explorer (I'm creating asp.net apps in vb) I no longer expand an .aspx page to display the .vb counterpart - I have to right click and view code.

Also, when adding a new file to the solution - the whole interface has changed, I don't get the master page checkbox option (I have to select a different filetype) nor do I have the choice of code-behind or not.

Are these just changes in Visual Studio? Confusingly it's also affected my VWD2008!

Finally, when I do create a new page - I get errors straight away.. i.e. "Could not load type 'XXXXXX.yyyyyy'." - Where XXXXXX is the project name, and yyyyyy is the class defined in the code-behind.  I'm also sure that prior to this, XXXXXX (the project name) was never even prepended to the class name! (removing it doesn't help)

I removed AnkhSVN but that didn't change anything... so was it the VS2008 install that caused this? Is it possible to change things back? I can make do with the cosmetic changes but the fact that a newly created blank page won't even compile is slightly annoying!!

If anyone can help I'd appreciate it!
cheers :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In comparing the code from previous pages to the ones that VS creates.. I realised that one piece of markup was not present in the new pages - that was the "CodeFile" property - so if I add that manually, everything's fine! No idea why this happens...

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed these too when I moved over...  They are likely changes in Visual Studio but also reflect changes in the .NET framework and compilers that come with the respective visual studio versions.

Comment: Any clues about the error? I've recently tested it by creating a blank solution, a stand-alone page works ok, but if I create a default master page, and a default page which uses that master page - then it won't compile with the error "Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'myApp.Site1'." - Site1 is the master page, myApp the solution.

Comment: Try changing it to Site1 instead of myApp.Site1.  I remember having that problem myself a couple times.  I think it has to do with some namespace issue, but I'm not 100% on that.